# Django: How can I localize my urls?

Tags: django

How can I localize my urls in Django?

```
url(u'^{0}/$'.format(_('register')), RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

I tried the above but it only seems to work when I stop and start the server. I guess that the urls are translated when the application start.

So if there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than just throwing `_()` in `urls.py`. You have spotted the reason yourself: The URLs are evaluated once, when Django starts, and not for every request. Therefore you will have to

a) put every possible translation in `urls.py`, or

b) implement routing yourself

### A. All in urls.py

```
url('hello', hello, name="hello_en"),
url('hallo', hello, name="hello_de"),
url('buenos_dias', hello, name="hello_es"),
```

Obviously not a nice solution, but it works for small projects.

### B. Implementing routing

That has it's own drawback, especially when it comes to use `reverse()`. However, it works in principle:

urls.py:

```
#...
url('(?<path>.+)', dispatcher),
#...
```

views.py:

```
def dispatcher(request, path):
    if path == "hallo":
        lang = "de"
    elif path == "buenos_dias":
        lang = "de"
    else:
        lang = "en"
```

Of course, you can make the lookup more intelligent, but then you have to make preassumptions:

```
# if request.session['language'] can be trusted:
def dispatcher(request, path):
    list_of_views = ['contact', 'about', 'foo']
    v = None
    for view in list_of_views:
        if _(view) == path:
            v = view
            break
    if v is None:
        # return 404 or the home page
```

Answer (score 1):

Internationalization of URLs has been introduced in django 1.4

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization

this is exactly what you are looking for